# Детект DER/CER/PEM сертификата

Tags: c#, json, json.net, x509certificate

Есть некоторый сервер, который перекидывает сертификат от одной системы к другой и появилась необходимость уменьшить объём передаваемых данных, отсюда пришла идея, что сертификат, который предоставлен уже в виде буквенно-цифровых символов, которые нормально передаются через json не кодировать в base64 и оставить подобное кодирование только для сертификатов в двоичной форме.

Проблема в том, что не понимаю, как можно узнать находится ли сертификат в PEM/DER кодировке (и соответственно, не нужно дополнительно кодировать в base64) или является CER сертификатов (и соответственно, нужно кодировать в base64 для передачи)

Оказалось, что используя штатный X509Certificate2 можно только различить ситуацию валидный сертификат и невалидный сертификат:

```
        try
        {
            var x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2();
            x509Certificate2.Import(data);
```

А вытащить информацию о том, что за тип у сертификата нельзя.

Как-то всё-таки это сделать правильно? Городить какие-то костыли проверяя регулярками что строка содержит только буквенно-цифровые символы кажется неправильной.

Comment: Вариант проверять разрешение файла не подходит? Чем это грозит?

Comment: @DaemonHK Я не хочу костыли, хочу сделать грамотно один раз и забыть.

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь, шарп не моя стезя, но может такая проверка подойдет? https://www.example-code.com/csharp/cert_convert_to_der.asp

Comment: @DaemonHK Не-а, там же тоже самое написано "It will auto-recognize the format and load appropiately"

Comment: Добавил альтернативно теги json и json.net на случай если есть какие-то готовые форматтеры, которые можно использовать в качестве fallback чтобы всю строку закодировать в base64 (У меня пока выходит так, что JsonConvert.SerializeObject не падает, а тупо отдельные спецсимволы эскейпит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы открыл файл и зачитал несколько первых байтов.

Если файл начинается с `-----BEGIN`, то это PEM формат.

Если файл начинается с `MII`, то это base64-encoded DER

Если файл начинается с байтов 0x30 0x82, то это бинарная DER кодировка ASN.1 объекта типа SEQUENCE, а все сертификаты, по стандарту, именно SEQUENCE. 0x82 означает, что размер структуры данных выражается двухбайтовым целым. Если стоит 0x83, то размер превышает 64 кб, что в принципе возможно для какого-нибудь CRL, но маловероятно для отдельного сертификата.

Может быть теоретически случай, когда второй байт 0x81. Это означает, что длина умещается в 1 байт, то есть размер объекта меньше 256 байтов. Я подозреваю, что это возможно, если взять ключи и подписи минимальных размеров и с минимумом символов в CN, но по нынешним временам такой сертификат надо заворачивать с порога)

В противном случае я не знаю, что это может быть.

Comment: В противном случае можно и кинуть исключение "не является известным типом сертификата". В конце концов я же всё равно предварительно делаю проверку, что x509Certificate2.Import считает что это какой-то валидный серт.